# contentsOfDirectoryAtPath: is not listing customized file extension

Tags: ios, file, customization

In my project (iOS), I have added some files with file extension (customized) ".dncx", for example. The customized file are visible in xcode project (Copt items into destination's.... checkbox is selected).
After using the following code, I'm printing the list of all the files.

```
NSArray *dirContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:resourcePath error:nil];
```

The files with .png, .wav, .plist, .jpg, extensions, all are getting printed, which are present in the same path along with customized files.

**But the files with the customized extension like, ".dncx" are not at all shown.**

Could you please guide me, making the customized file extensions listed.

Comment: What does this have to do with xcode?

Comment: I need to get the file names, programatticaly. Then, I use those files in other functions, as an array. -Arun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those files are obviously not in the directory that you think they are. I've put some `dncx` file in my bundle (and in `Documents`) without incident.

Typical problems include:

- If you're looking for these files in your bundle, the question is whether they were included in the bundle at all. If you open your target settings, choose "Build Phases" tab, expand "Copy Bundle Resources" and see if your dcnx files are listed there; if not, add them there by clicking the "+" button immediately at the end of the list of "Copy Bundle Resources";

  [image: copy bundle resources]
- Again, if you're looking for these files in your bundle, make sure they weren't accidentally put in another folder within the bundle;
- If you want to externally confirm the contents of your bundle or `Documents` folder, I would run the app on the simulator and then navigate to the folder in question (e.g. "~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/ ..." and see if they're there ... you might want to go to Terminal and type in `chflags nohidden ~/Library` if your `Library` folder is hidden in Finder (which it is by default)). To see inside the bundle, once you've navigated to the app itself, <kbd>control</kbd>-click on that (or right-click) and choose "Show Package Contents"

Comment: Thank you so much. It works fine, after adding the files through 'Build phases'.